# how to check all array elements with each others in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
let me explain my question with examples:
// let arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
I would like to compare all of them:
1 === 2
1 === 3
1 === 4
1 === 5
2 === 3
2 === 4
2 === 5
3 === 4
3 === 5
4 === 5
```

I am trying to use if statement if true 'do this', that would be great if you guys can solve this problem most efficient way, really appreacite it.
thank you an advance

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code writing service. You need to show what you have attempted so far, and where you are stuck/having issues, and then we can help you solve those problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `for` inside `for`:

```
for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
for(var j = 1; j < arr.length; j++) {
    if(arr[i] === arr[j]) {
        console.log("ok");
    }
}}
```

i[0] will be compared with j[0], j[1], j[2], j[3], j[4]

and i[1] will be compared with j[0], j[1], j[2], j[3], j[4]

Comment: `i` should start from 0 and `j` should start from `i`, so that every couple is checked only once

Comment: based on his question, you'd want your inner loop to be `for(var j = i+1;...`. That way you're not comparing 0 with 0, 1 with 1, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will make you happy? :)

```js
const testArray = (arr) => arr.sort().join() === arr.sort().reverse().join()

const typedTestArray = (arr) => testArray(arr) && testArray(arr.map(x => typeof x))


console.log('Must be true', testArray([1, 1, 1, 1]))
console.log('Must be false', testArray([1, 0, 0, 1]))
console.log('Must be false', testArray(['happy', 'sad']))
console.log('Must be false', typedTestArray([1, '1', 1, 1]))
```

**UPD:**
Added typedTestArray() to check types equality also, for case from comments to my answer: `[2, 2, '2', 2]`

**UPD2:**
Rewritten with arrow functions to make it look shorter and cleaner. 
So my intention was just to find a solution without using loops. This one without check for types can be wrtitten in one line and seems to be working.

Comment: but this does not make any sense!! for example `[1,2,2,1]` results `true`

Comment: @Francesco, good point, thanks. Added sort(). Not so elegant, but solves this case.

Comment: what for `[2,2,'2',2]`? should be true or false?

Comment: @Francesco It depends... It also can be tested same way if needed. But we don't know how author going to use it. Anyway, this case also worth mentioning, thanks.

Comment: I really like your `reverse` approach; I give you another approach: `[1,1,1,1].every((element, index, array) => element === array[0])`

Comment: @Francesco Cool! Like it. Much shorter and without dancing with types. But seems, I was looking for a solution to misinterpreted question. :)

Answer (score -1):

We know that for all of the elements to be equal to each other, they must all be equal to the first element in the array. If `arr[0] === arr[1]` and `arr[0] === arr[2]`, then surely `arr[1] === arr[2]`. For that reason, we only need to check each element against the first element. We can use a for loop for this.

```
for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if(arr[i] !== arr[0]) {
        return false;
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: what about `[0, 1, 1, 2, 3]`? The second and third elements are equal, but neither are equal to the first element.

Comment: @David784 I interpreted the question as "check if ALL elements are equal with all other elements."